# How to get the "real" position of a row in the data table

Tags: c#, datatable

I have tried many ways such as using Find(txtID.Text) or DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(.... = txtID.Text) function but these functions fail if the format of Textbox and format of data are different. How can I find that row without using the .Text . attribute

For example:

```
DataRow _row = _tb.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Code") == txtBookID.Text).FirstOrDefault();
DataRow _row2 = _tb.Rows.Find(txtBookID.Text);
```

Comment: You will need to sort(.Sort) the DataTable first. Then loop and get the DataRow you want

Comment: What format are you talking about? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Maybe you could provide some examples of what you expect to match and explain why.

Comment: @WeiChenChen, there's unlike to be any sorting required and you can't sort a `DataTable` anyway. All that is likely required is to change the condition specified to the `Where` method but we need a proper explanation of the problem to know what it should be changed to.

Comment: What you _should_ be doing is defining Primary Key columns in the `DataTable` and then you can retrieve rows by key-value instead of by some arbitrary ordered index.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to call `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`. Just call `FirstOrDefault` and pass the condition to it directly.

Comment: I already set the primary key of the data table, the difference in the format I am talking about is the font, the font of the textbox may be different from the font of the data. Can data binding help in this case?

Comment: _the "real" position of a row_ there is no such thing as rows in a database are always and by definition unordered until you order your query. Not even a relative position is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: Try following : var row = _tb.AsEnumerable().Select((x,i) => new {code = x.Field<string>("Code"), index = i)}).Where(x => x.code == txtBookID.Text).FirstOrDefault();